# Integration via Weierstraß substitution and u-substitution on $\int{\dfrac{\cos{x}}{2+\sin{x}}} dx$ yields seemingly different results

Tags: real-analysis, integration, indefinite-integrals

I tried finding $\int{\dfrac{\cos{x}}{2+\sin{x}}}dx$ via Weierstraß substitution: $t = \tan{\frac{x}{2}}$ and alternatively via $u = 2 + \sin{x}$.

The first approach results in a rational function in $t$, applying partial fraction decomposition and solving elementary integrals. Eventually it yields
$$\log{\left(\frac{1}{2}\sin{(x)}+1\right)}$$

The second approach is more straight forward and gives

$$\log{(\sin{(x)}+2)}$$

Are these expressions potentially equal since I could not find any computation error.

Comment: It's important to keep track of delimiters. The antiderivatives should be $\log\left(\frac12\sin x+1\right)$ and $\log\left(\sin x+2\right)$. Now use the fact that $\log(ab) = \log a + \log b$ to reconcile them.

Comment: @user170231 right, but $\log{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}+\log{(\sin{(x)}+2)} \neq \log{(\sin{(x)}+2)}$ or am I mistaken?

Comment: There's a constant of integration....

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen right, thank you. And the constant they differ is $\log{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}$